# Django-blog-zinnia not displaying admin CSS/Javascript properly

Tags: django, django-admin, zinnia

I am having the following problem with [Django-blog-zinnia](http://django-blog-zinnia.com/), please see the picture below. My static files are being served on Amazon S3, this includes the CSS and Javascript in the screen shot below. I can properly trace all of the static files to a source (meaning all of them can be found). I get no error messages, so I am having a hard time tracing the root of this problem.

[image: Django blog zinnia not displaying Javascript properly]

As you can see,  the entry content field is not displaying, if you are unfamiliar of what this should look, look at [this link](http://the-dig.com/blog/media/uploads/Picture_.png). What could be causing this problem? Or better yet, is there a good way to debug these kind of problems?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. Just found this thread and it gives what looks like the answer:

> do you serve the static files from another domain ?
> If so, it's normal that wymeditor doesn't work, it's a known limitation.
>
> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/django-blog-zinnia/wymeditor/django-blog-zinnia/kfgj19-3lGc

This would explain why it works fine for me on local and not fine on staging/production. Have you figured out a workaround?